# Is "a pretend conversation" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

I was watching a movie (native speakers) and I noticed this sentence:

> 'She was having a pretend conversation on the phone...'

Is it grammatically correct? I checked the word "pretend" with *Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary* - it said "pretend" only exists in verb form. I couldn't find any other cases of using a verb + a noun to form a noun phrase like this.

I think it should be constructed thus: `verb with -ing or -ed + noun = noun phrase`. Am I right? Alternatively, if the speaker is right, please enlighten me and give me some examples in which this kind of grammar applies.

Comment: @sumelic No, my  OALD (4th ed.) does not seem to carry that definition: there are only 3, all as verbs.

Comment: The dictionary showed me only 1 form of "pretend" and it's "v" with only 2 examples of how to use it in verb form :(

Comment: The conversation *was* pretend - 'pretend' describes the conversation. As a native speaker, that construction is fine but I'm not sure about exactly why!

Comment: @marcellothearcane Correct, but I can't really explain why either. It's also like how children "play pretend".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"A pretend conversation" is grammatically correct. People who are inclined to call any word that can be placed before a noun to modify its meaning an "adjective" classify *pretend* as an adjective when it is used like this; I'm not sure about this classification, but you can think of it that way if you find it helpful. The division between parts of speech can often seem blurry in English; *pretend* can also be used as a noun.

The online version of the Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary seems to have a definition of *[pretend](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pretend?a=british)* as an adjective:

> **pretend** adjective
>
> **imaginary or not real**:
>
> - *"Do you want a cup of tea?" she asks, offering me a pretend cup.*
> - *They knew the argument was only pretend, but they still got upset.*"

*Pretend* doesn't behave exactly like a typical adjective though.
It can also be used as a noun, as in "they were playing pretend." (I found mention of this in the Oxford English Dictionary.)

I would say it is definitely no more of an adjective than the word *[fun](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/224085/fun-part-of-speech/224121#224121).* Like *fun,* *pretend* can be used:

- as an uncountable noun: "You mustn't be afraid of pretend" (1965 G. McInnes *Road to Gundagai* iii. 54, cited in the Oxford English Dictionary)
- as a predicate after a form of *to be*: "It was all pretend"
- as an attributive word modifying a following noun: "a pretend conversation" (your example)

*Pretend* is not like a normal adjective mainly in that it is not "gradable":

- We can't add the adjective suffixes *-er* or *-est* to *pretend*
- People also don't say things like "very pretend"

Actually, this probably makes it less of an adjective than *fun* ( ["funner" and "funnest"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4066/is-funnest-a-word) are stigmatized, but have some use, and "[very fun](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=very%20fun%2C%20very%20pretend&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvery%20fun%3B%2Cc0)" does exist for some people, although other people find it ungrammatical).

Another similar word is *[make-believe](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/make-believe).* This also started out as a verb, but is now also used as an uncountable noun, as a predicate after *be,* and as an attributive "adjective":

> - the children **made believe** they were doctors
> - She squandered millions on a life of **make-believe**.
> - The violence in those films was too unreal, it was **make-believe.**
> - 'But, why?' he asked in **make-believe** astonishment.

(Example sentences from the Collins English Dictionary)

Comment: Oh man, so which offline dictionary should I use to get me out of confusing situations like this ? I think I've experienced this before. Really annoying ! your make-believe reminded me of Sony's slogan

Comment: @CuteLad: Sorry, I'm not sure because I only use online dictionaries nowadays! I have heard [good things about the American Heritage Dictionary in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/95?m=33000810#33000810).

Comment: @CuteLad It's best to go for online dictionaries if you can, because they're updated frequently.